# Resize handles for Android Text View

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, textview

I am trying to achieve resize handle for text view. I have created the normal text view. But I am looking to resize the text view by dragging the resize handles, like we do when we scale and image or while cropping. Please review the following image to have better idea on what, I am looking for.

[Link to image demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfvOg.jpg)

Comment: https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView ?

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij .. Thank you for the reply. But that one is not helping